# Joining two tables in SQL Server when one table has huge data and other has few data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I want to join two tables (not inner join), Left table has huge data (millions of record), and right table has few records. What should I prefer  (Left or Right Outer join) and why.

Comment: The common way to join tables in SQL is by using the `JOIN` keyword.  That fact is independent of the size of the tables.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this  means while joining two table the size doesn't matter... whether i do left outer or right outer. There will not be any performance impact.

Comment: Wouldn't an outer join in either direction take just as long as every row in A must be compared with every row in B

Comment: You will rarely have a reason to use `right join` in queries. What you need to determine is which table should be the outer table of a left join.

Comment: The optimizer will figure out the best way to match regardless of what side the larger table is on.

Comment: Well stated, Joe.  Second-guessing the database engine is almost always a bad thing to do.  This isn't the 1960s, where we wrinkled our brows over how to set up a problem, and how many disk sectors to allocate for scratch files.

Comment: @MurtazaBadshah . . . You use the `JOIN` that is appropriate for the problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all That join is independent of the size of the tables

Well I think this depends what data you want either from Left table or from right table  let us assume you have two tables Employees which has millions of records let us put this in right and Department which has 10 record put it in left Now each employee has one department.

**Employee**

- EmpID
- DepartmentId

  **Department**
- DepartmentId
- Department Name

Now Suppose You want to know which employee belongs to which Department Use This Query.

```
Select e.empId,d.DepartmentName
from employee e
join department d
on e.departmentid=d.departmentid
```

Now Suppose You want to know which employee has now assigned any department 
use the below query

```
 Select e.empId,d.DepartmentName
from employee e
left join department d
on e.departmentid=d.departmentid
where d.departmentid is null
```

Now Suppose You want to know how many employees which depratment use the below query

```
Select d.[Department Name],COUNT(e.empID) from Employee e
left join Department d
on e.DepartmentId=d.DepartmentId
group by d.[Department Name]
```

For more information about joins please use the below image
[image: Sql Joins]